# Terraform custom provider pass IP to provisioner

Tags: terraform

I'm working on a custom Terraform provider that manages resources on a remote HyperV cluster.

Once the VM resource is created I'd like to invoke the remote-exec provisioner.

How do I pass the host argument to the remote-exec provisioner?

For example, I would like to populate the host value with the IP of test. (Once an IP is provided by DHCP)

```
provisioner "hyperv-winrm" {
  vm_name      = "test"

  connection {
    type     = "winrm"
    user     = "Administrator"
    password = "${var.admin_password}"
    host     = "<<IP/DNS GOES HERE>>"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using Terraform to create the VM? AFAIK Terraform doesn't have a HyperV provider so would be good to see what you're doing here.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'm developing my own HyperV provider, about to answer my own question now. Thanks.

Comment: Okay cool. The answer almost certainly boils down to using `${self.private_ip}` but that relies on the resource exporting that as an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the answer.

From the resource create function: (Can be update, delete etc..)

```
func resourceVMCreate(d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{}) error {

    // Create VM
    // Wait for IP

    // Set connection info which will be used by provisioner
    d.SetConnInfo(map[string]string{
        "type": "winrm",
        "host": *vm.IpAddress,
        "user": *vm.UserName,
        "password": *vm.Password
    }

    return err
}
```